# How to stop OnSceneGUI slider drag event with ExecuteEvents in Unity editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax

I'm no coder so I've spent a few days trying to figure out a way to stop the current slider from being dragged, but I can't figure out the syntax to get this to work.
I assume ExecuteEvents is what I'm looking for but I don't know how to.

```cs
void OnSceneGUI()
{
    if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown && Event.current.button == 1 && cancel)
    {
        cancel = false;
        ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerUpHandler>(PointerEventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject, new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current), ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);
        slider = 0;
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the slider with `PointerEventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject`
but it causes the following error,

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'PointerEventData.pointerCurrentRaycast'`and I don't know
>   why. I am using`UnityEngine.EventSystems.

I'm also not sure if this is the right approach so. I don't mind some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Well because [`pointerCurrentRaycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData-pointerCurrentRaycast.html) is **not** a `static` member. It belongs to a specific **instance** of this type and you will need that instance's reference in order to access that value.

---

Don't know if this solves what you actually are trying to do but you probably can create your own `PointerEventData` instance at your mouse position and use a Raycast to get the object you are hovering. Something like

```
void OnSceneGUI()
{
    if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown && Event.current.button == 1 && cancel)
    {
        cancel = false;

        var pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
         pointer.position = Input.mousePosition;

         List<RaycastResult> raycastResults = new List<RaycastResult>();
         EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointer, raycastResults);

         if(raycastResults.Count > 0)
         {
             var obj = raycastResults[0].gameObject;

            ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerUpHandler>(obj, pointer, ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);
            slider = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it matters but when you say to get the object I'm hovering, is that really correct? I need the object last clicked (the slider) and when you use a slider you are not really hovering it as you drag.
  
I also tried your suggestion and it gave an error:

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Boo.Lang.List<UnityEngine.EventSystems.RaycastResult>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.EventSystems.RaycastResult>'

Comment: @polo then don't use a `Boo.Lang.List` but rather make sure you everywhere are `using System.Collections.Generic` instead

Comment: I see, never would have guessed that you have multiple choices for namespace.  Anyway, this causes a new problem. `var obj = raycastResult[0].gameObject; The name 'raycastResult' does not exist in the current context`. If I add `object raycastResult;` I get this error for the same line: `Cannot apply indexing with[] to an expression of type 'object'`

Comment: @polo Well that was me typing on the phone and missing an `s` ;) it's `raycastResults[0]`, the list we declared 5 lines above ;)

Comment: Ah you're right, I was so confused why it didn't accept it, I never even considered the spelling. That's embarrassing. Thanks for the help, unfortunately it's not the correct way to get the slider object and/or send the event to it. But now when I don't have to struggle with the syntax I can try out different ways.

Comment: To expand on this: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` and it comes from `EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointer, raycastResults);` and I guess that you actually need to get the raycast that Unity does when you click on the scene UI.

Comment: Do you have an EventSystem in your Scene? The only thing that can be null here is EventSystem.current which should only happen if there is no EventSystem in the scene afaik

Comment: I couldn't tell you, I have not made one and I don't know how it works. My script is a custom editor script that modifies certain components in the current selection.